# How to get the relative distance of nested div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/SzwFg/2/) <---See Fiddle

Here I want to return the relative distance of two divs with their parent div. It seem that `.offsetTop`cannot return a correct answer. The result I expected is marked as green lines, the distance in 2 and 3.

[image]

And it's strange that why the border of their parent div was also included in the of `.offsetTop`?

Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle is boxes `2` and `3`, not `1` and `2`..

Comment: Also, the `offsetParent` is `<body>`, not the parent `<div>`. see console in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zz3hL/

Comment: @Paul S sorry I put on an old pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you gave .paper{ position:relative }, then the children would have coords offsets relative to it?

http://codepen.io/snypelife/pen/AqtIC

Comment: That's absolutely the key! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just subtract the parent's offset top as well:

```
var re = document.getElementById("result");

var num2 = document.getElementById("2");
var num2Parent = num2.parentNode;

var num3 = document.getElementById("3");
var num3Parent = num3.parentNode;
re.innerHTML="position:<br/>box1 = "+ (num2.offsetTop - num2Parent.offsetTop)+"<br/>box2 = "+ (num3.offsetTop - num3Parent.offsetTop) ;
```